# What is this brown seed pod found under a large evergreen tree?

Tags: identification, seeds

Please help me to identify the seed.
I was thinking it was a sweetgum tree of some kind, but then it is a bit different, so I remain in doubts.
I attach the image of the pod and the tree under which it was found in great quantity.
It is taken in South Florida.
I would appreciate any input.

[image: seed][image: tree]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Casuarina equisetifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casuarina_equisetifolia) or "Australian Pine". It's an invasive species from Australia.

See [Florida Fish and Wildlife Conservation Commission](http://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/invasive-plants/weed-alerts/australian-pine).

[Here's](http://skipsflorida.blogspot.ca/2011/10/floridas-mystery-tree.html) a nice anecdote by someone else who was flummoxed by its identity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So.... burn it with fire?